# How to make te lines disappear?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, creative-cloud

I draw quilts, then use the bucket tool to "fill" or color them in.
But I need the lines to drop out, after I am done.

I am working in illustrator cc - self taught, so I don't know which drawer the socks are in.

Can you help?  Working on a deadline, of course....

---

Thanks for all of the suggestions.  I will try a few.
I am looking for a way to globally "drop out" all of the lines it takes to draw a quilt, once it has been "colored".  It seems like I used to be able to do this in CS3....but now am using current CC.
To do each line individually would be too cumbersome.
Is it just a matter of creating the lines on one layer and the color on another layer?  Would that do it?

Okay,  my apologies for being so "self taught" about this.
I will try some of your ideas.

Now that you have seen the images, maybe this will inspire some other comments?

Thanks again, everyone!
Natalie.

[image: illustrator cc example of quilt drawing]

Comment: Do you have some examples to show us (screenshots)?

Comment: Object -> Expand. Then you'll be able to click into the object and erase the lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can select all shapes, you want to remove strokes (lines) from, then go to the Object->Path->Outline Stroke. Then double click on Magic Wand tool, type minimum value 1 in the tolerance field, to avoid unwanted selection, then select lines with Magic Wand tool and press delete button.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well that's nice, after all these years I never noticed there was  an outline stroke and always used expand. In fact I never even used the magic wand in Illustrator  :)

Comment: You can do it with Expand too, but if there are some gradients or blend shadows or etc, you don't want to Expand, Outline Stroke method is better.

Comment: Why not just make all strokes color none? I dont get it, seems like 2 steps too much work.

Comment: You can change stroke opacity to zero also. There are several ways to disappear lines, depends what is your main goal.